# Re-initializing a Realm object in a different thread

Tags: ios, swift, realm, grand-central-dispatch

Is running a query the only way of re-initializing a Realm `Object` for use in a different thread?  Is there no way to somehow grab some kind of reference for use with Realm, so that the query doesn't have to be completely from scratch?  It would be nice to have some kind of guarantee that the object is for the same record (if it exists and the query for that "ref" is successful), without having to add a primary key just for this one purpose.

This outlines my situation:

```
func construct(name: String, tokens: [String]) -> Document {
    let doc = Document()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(doc)
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        // Some long running task to convert `tokens` into `[Blurb]`
        // var blurbs: [Blurb]

        // What's the recommended way of re-initing that new `Document`?
        // let sameDoc = .....

        try! realm.write {
            sameDoc.blurbs.append(blurbs)
        }
    }

    return doc
}
```

Comment: I think there is an only way using a primary key can be guaranteed to be the same value. Why you would not use a primary key?

Comment: I'd like to not have to add a primary key for this one purpose.  Since I have access to the record at this moment, I was hoping there was some less heavy handed approach to passing some sort of reference to the scope.

Comment: If this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/3946 would be merged, you may be able to pass objects across threads. In the meanwhile, the ways are using primary key or querying all properties, I think.

Comment: Ah, yea that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.  I'll subscribe to that PR and just continue with a primary key for now.